# Using the brew install of lua, make file can't find lua.h

Tags: lua, homebrew

I am trying to install lalarm from here:
[https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/](https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/)

I installed lua on a macOS using `brew install lua`

and when I go to the library directory to make it, this is what happens

```
%> make
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -O2 -I/usr/local/include -o alarm.so -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup lalarm.c 
lalarm.c:12:10: fatal error: 'lua.h' file not found
#include "lua.h"
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Where does homebrew install the lua.h file?

How do I get that to be recognized by default from make?

Comment: If you change `"lua.h"` to `<lua.h>`, and similarly for any other Lua headers it uses, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lua.h` is not in `/usr/local/include`:

```
$ fd lua /usr/local/include
$
```

You need to configure the `CFLAGS` to include `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lua/5.4.4_1/include/lua`:

```
$ fd lua.h /opt/homebrew/Cellar/lua/5.4.4_1
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lua/5.4.4_1/include/lua/lua.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lua/5.4.4_1/include/lua/lua.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lua/5.4.4_1/include/lua5.4/lua.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lua/5.4.4_1/include/lua5.4/lua.hpp
```